# Get and send a file with SCP using options

Tags: scp

How to write `scp user@url:/tmp/foo ./` with options instead of one-liner ?

I tried this, but unsuccessfully:

```
scp -l user url /tmp/foo ./
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Anyway, scp will copy local files, local to remote, remote to local or even between two remotes. And for that it uses the `user@host:path` format to recognize which of its arguments is the remote part. Does it have to be scp? Maybe `sftp`'s arguments are more the way you want.

Comment: @dratenik When `user` looks like `root@foo:bar`, I need to use `ssh -l root@foo:bar server`, I have a similar issue with `scp`, but using `-l` option doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Send file

```
scp -o user=myuser foo.txt myserver:/my/folder
```

#### Get file

```
scp -o user=myuser myserver:/my/folder/foo.txt ./
```